# Why does the elasticsearch suggesters return multiple equal objects?

Tags: elasticsearch, search-suggestion

I'm playing with suggesters currently and wonder why the resultset has always multiple equal objects.

Example request:

```
{"suggest": {
    "test" : {
        "text": "holz",
        "term" : {
            "field":"title"
        }
    }
}}
```

Result:

```
{"suggest": {
   "test": [
     {
        "text": "holz",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 4,
        "options": [...]
     },
     {
        "text": "holz",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 4,
        "options": [...]
     },
     {
        "text": "holz",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 4,
        "options": [...]
     },
     {
        "text": "holz",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 4,
        "options": [...]
     }
  ]
}}
```

Even the objects in `options` are exactly the same. It's always the same, no matter what text I want suggestions for. Is there any explanation for this?

ES version is 2.3.4

Comment: Same at version 6.7.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html#skip_duplicates

You have to add the skip duplicates param.

Have a nice day,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding payloads to your docs ?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-suggesters-completion.html

```
curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/music/song/1?refresh=true' -d '{
"name" : "Nevermind",
"suggest" : {
    "input": [ "Nevermind", "Nirvana" ],
    "output": "Nirvana - Nevermind",
    **"payload" : { "artistId" : 2321 },**
    "weight" : 34
}
```

}'